# Trying to understand how the deletion of hard links relate to the freeing up of values in the inode table?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4, inode

When a hard link is deleted, the link is removed but the contents of the file itself continue to exist (that is, its space is not deallocated) until all links to the file are deleted.

My understanding is that **only** when the file itself is deleted does the Inode table reset for this particular file? Since even the original file is a link represented by a **1** in the ls command's meta data.

Let's say, for example, I have 2 hard links to a file and I delete both hard links, the Inode data is still indexed in the table until the last link is deleted? Is this correct?

Upon using the command `df -hi` it does not relate much info whether or not space has been cleared. So, my second question is how can I know for sure when Inode data is clear and not taking up space?

Answer (score 3):

An inode's space will be released and its block and space in the inode table when:

- The last directory entry pointing at the inode is deleted.  That is, there are no more hard links to the inode, and
- The last file descriptor referencing the inode is closed.  That is, the inode is no longer in use and the inode has no open file descriptors referencing it.

For example, a process might create a file, open the file, and then immediately unlink it in order to use that file as a temporary store.  If the process exits, or is otherwise killed, its file descriptors are automatically closed, and the temporary file is automatically released.

Until the inode is actually released, the inode and its blocks will be in use, and the used space will be seen as used blocks and inodes as displayed by df.  When the last file descriptor and hard link are gone, then the space will be released and the reporting by df will be so updated.